# How to embed to HTML flash emulator for interactive map SWF file - that is not ruffle

Tags: flash, embed, emulation, ruffle

I have an issue to convert SWF file to HTML using emulator, unfortunately Ruffle is not supporting all features in ActionScript3 showing console error for AVM2. I tried to embed that in project that is Asp Net Razor MVC. However I am interested is some another emulator or tool to embed it. I found WAflash demo works perfect but there is no info in their documentation, also I tried to conve
rt my scripts in Adobe Animate but not much time to rewrite whole javascript. If anyone had experience with this, I would appreciate help :)